# How to parse a json string in SQL Server 2012

Tags: json, sql-server

I have a json string data.

```
{ "salesremarks": { "InternalCode":0, "Remark":"" },
  "OTH": { "ZALO_DYN":"", "Payment_mode":"1", "Max_req_EIR":"55" }........
```

Is there any way to parse this data type in SQL Server 2012?

I use string function for this, but they are also failed

Comment: Are you sure the version is `MS SQL Server 2010` ?

Comment: Do you really need to parse your JSON content inside a database?

Comment: Is there a way?  Yes.  Is SQL Server the right tool to do string parsing?  No.

Comment: I'm sorry all. I mistypo. It's exactly Ms sql server 2012.

Comment: If there is no way to parse json for before SQL 2016. So how can I split this large string based on some key words for this large string. Thank you.

Comment: I saw this a while back.  Haven't had time to see how well it works.  https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/consuming-json-strings-in-sql-server/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL Server 2016 has functions to parse it, for previous versions you will need to parse it yourself. Here is a parsing example for your sample data :

```
declare @STRING varchar(max);
declare @SalesRemarks_InternalCode varchar(256);
declare @SalesRemarks_Remark varchar(256);
declare @OTH_ZALO_DYN varchar(256);
declare @OTH_Payment_mode varchar(256);
declare @OTH_Max_req_EIR varchar(256);

set @STRING = '{ "salesremarks": { "InternalCode":0, "Remark":"" }, "OTH": { "ZALO_DYN":"", "Payment_mode":"1", "Max_req_EIR":"55" } }'

set @SalesRemarks_InternalCode = substring(@STRING, charindex('"InternalCode"', @STRING) + 15, charindex(',', substring(@STRING, charindex('"InternalCode"', @STRING) + 16, 8000)))    
set @SalesRemarks_Remark = substring(@STRING, charindex('"Remark"', @STRING) + 10, charindex('"', substring(@STRING, charindex('"Remark"', @STRING) + 10, 8000)) - 1)    
set @OTH_ZALO_DYN = substring(@STRING, charindex('"ZALO_DYN"', @STRING) + 12, charindex('"', substring(@STRING, charindex('"ZALO_DYN"', @STRING) + 12, 8000)) - 1)    
set @OTH_Payment_mode = substring(@STRING, charindex('"Payment_mode"', @STRING) + 16, charindex('"', substring(@STRING, charindex('"Payment_mode"', @STRING) + 16, 8000)) - 1)    
set @OTH_Max_req_EIR = substring(@STRING, charindex('"Max_req_EIR"', @STRING) + 15, charindex('"', substring(@STRING, charindex('"Max_req_EIR"', @STRING) + 15, 8000)) - 1)

select @SalesRemarks_InternalCode as SalesRemarks_InternalCode, @SalesRemarks_Remark as SalesRemarks_Remark, @OTH_ZALO_DYN as OTH_ZALO_DYN, @OTH_Payment_mode as OTH_Payment_mode, @OTH_Max_req_EIR as OTH_Max_req_EIR
```

Result :

```
+---------------------------+---------------------+--------------+------------------+-----------------+
| SalesRemarks_InternalCode | SalesRemarks_Remark | OTH_ZALO_DYN | OTH_Payment_mode | OTH_Max_req_EIR |
+---------------------------+---------------------+--------------+------------------+-----------------+
| 0                         |                     |              | 1                | 55              |
+---------------------------+---------------------+--------------+------------------+-----------------+
```